# security module for SSH on Cisco 6500

Tags: cisco, cisco-6500

do anyone know if there is a SSH module, or any secure module that provides SSH for Cisco 6500 series of routers/switches?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSH on the 6500 series is a software feature, so the best thing to do is use the  [Cisco Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/) to select a software image with SSH support and install that.

Comment: So a hardware module is not available for 6500 series!? I mean any module that can provide us with SSH for secure remote control of device.

Comment: Why would you need a hardware module for that? It's a software feature like SSH running on any OS like Windows, Linux whatever. This is for management. If you are talking about encrypting user traffic that is something entirely different.

Comment: Yes, this is for management. So there is no need for hardware module linecard. Just to find the proper IOS that support SSH

Comment: Yes, it's all in the management software, no additional hardware is required.

Answer (score 0):

SSH management is available on pretty much all IOS versions available for enterprise class switches.

Generic setup:

```
aaa new-model
user foo password 0 foobar
hostname foo
!-- generate SSH key
crypto key generate rsa
!-- key length
1024
!-- specify SSH ver
ip ssh ver 2
!
line vty 0 4
transport input ssh
```

That's all there is.  Then SSH to the management IP and login.

Comment: Not entirely true - the hardware has to support a CRYPTO-compatible image for the SSH feature to work. Not *all* hardware does, but the overwhelming majority does.

Comment: He specified a 6500.  That's a big boy that supports CRYPTO.

Comment: @connorwa John Jensen is correct, not ALL IOS versions have SSH. Just replace "on all IOS switches" with "on pretty much every IOS image that's out for the 6500".

Comment: Okay, that's a fair cop.  Done.

Comment: Actually, not *every* IOS image has crypto - they make IOS images for export to munitions-controlled countries (i.e. China, Iran, etc.) Look for the string 'k9' in the image name, i.e. `s2t54-ipservicesk9_npe-mz.SPA.151-2.SY1.bin` which means it has the requisite crypto software included.

Comment: @WillDennis That's why he said "on pretty much all IOS versions available for enterprise class switches". SSH functionality IS available for every supervisor module made for the 6500 series chassis; it just depends on the IOS version.